# Jaskson Json Serialize Polymorphic with inheritance

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, polymorphism

Trying to serialize Json to Object they has been implemented and has non-primitive data type. Here is the code that i'm trying to run.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = 
 JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class, name = "Child")
})
public interface Parent {

}
```

.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "cdata"
})
public class Child implements Serializable, Parent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 34658537546173718L;

    @JsonProperty("cdata")
    private Cdata cdata;
}
```

.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "version"
})
public class Cdata implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7706669244151885541L;

    private String version;
}
```

.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
mapper.configure( MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true );
Parent parent = mapper.readValue("jsonString", Parent.class);
```

This is the Error i get when i run the above code:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'cdata' as a subtype of [simple type, class Child]: known type ids = [Child]
>    at

Comment: can you please share Cdata class as well?

Comment: why are you reading Parent.class? it should be Child.class right? in mapper.readValue

Comment: The reason is i want to use polymorphism to read in multiple flavor of child without creating new readValue(). Eg. child1...n can all implement Parent class and the above code doesn't have to change to serialize the child class.

Comment: @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Chils.class, name = "Child"), here what is Chils.class?i think it should be Child right?

Comment: Ya it should be child. Looks like I made that error when copying.

Comment: Can you post the JSON you're deserializing? I suspect the deserializer is reading the value "cdata" when trying to determine the object type from the wrapper.

Comment: {
      "cdata": {
      “version": "v1"
      }
   }

Comment: So i'm trying to do this ((Child) parent).getVersion();

Comment: Because you've specified using a wrapper class to extract type info, Jackson is assuming the subclass name is `'cdata'` which does not exist so it throws an exception. Try serializing your object and print out the result so you know what the input JSON needs to look like.

Comment: @Baldy You are correct when i serialize the object i got back 
`{".Child": { "cdata": { “version": "v1" } } }` 
Is there way to have the Json output as i described above?

Comment: You need some data in the input stream so that Jackson knows what subtype to create on deserialization. Instead of a wrapper class, you could also use a field value which would leave your structure largely intact.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after little help from @Baldy. I figure out that 
changing default type to OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE solved the issue.

`mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE);`

Comment: That will work as long as you have a single subtype. The minute you have two or more subtypes, you'll need to add the type information in the dataset somehow.

Comment: You're right i may have celebrated too early. Now i'm getting 
    `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of Parent (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information...`